# I need to know that how can I add multiple vendor cost customization on shopping cart page

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

Basically, I have 5 vendors so I need to add shipping cost like this.

1. If any customer selects one product from the first vendor then price
   added 15 dollars.
2. And if user select product from any other vendor then prices added
   10 dollars in shipping cart.

So I need any tutorials or extension or any code please help ASAP.

Comment: You can use extra fee for this functionality.

Comment: any tutorial or link how can i do that ?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-extra-fee.html

Comment: can i customize that i need functionality like this

1
down vote
favorite
Basically, I have 5 vendors so I need to add shipping cost like this.

If any customer selects one product from the first vendor then price added 15 dollars.
And if user select product from any other vendor then prices added 10 dollars in shipping cart.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cart Rules unless you need custom modules.

[Magento DevDocs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html)